# How to synchronize posts in priv/static with database in an Elixir Phoenix blog?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to implement a blog with Elixir and Phoenix.
The posts are written in markdown, and the files are in priv/posts directory.

I succeed to implement this solution and it's working fine.

But i would like to add comments in my blog, so i have to store the posts in database and add a relation for the comments.

I don't know how to sync the files in priv with the database, i tried to run a function in a GenServer (where i retrieve all posts when server start) to check if a post already exist in database, by his slug, but it's not working.

Is there a good approach to sync the files with database ? Or another solution to add comments ?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a service like [disqus](https://disqus.com/) for comments. They have a free tier.

(I don't have any experience with this service but maybe it works for you.)